# Shared pointers: why no double free?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, double-free

Why does this code NOT generate a double free when the shared pointers go out of scope?

```
int main()
{
    {
        auto * ptr = new int(1);
        shared_ptr<int> a( ptr );
        shared_ptr<int> b( ptr );
        cout << "ok: " << *a << *b << endl;
    }
    cout << "still ok" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh! I know fear!

Comment: As other are pointing out, you are actually double deleting a pointer, so you are in the realm of UB. using a class instead of an int can help you to see the proble: see [this](https://ideone.com/I2gnHj) as example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does this code NOT generate a double free when the shared pointers
>   go out of scope?

Why do you think it doesn't?

It's undefined behavior, anything can happen. That includes your program printing out `still ok`.

Comment: Truth is: I was erroneously thinking that it wasn't crashing only because on my machine it was not crashing. I forgot that undefined behavior is a thing.

Answer (score 6):

This code is UB, so *anything* might happen.

For `a` *delete* is called on the already deleted pointer.

Answer (score 4):

Constructing more than one shared pointer from a raw pointer results in [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) because:

> the pointed-to object will have multiple control blocks.

<sup>Excerpt from the "Effective Modern C++", page 129, item 19</sup>

Avoid passing raw pointers to a `std::shared_ptr` constructor. If you really must use raw pointers then use the result of a operator `new` instead of a pointer:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> a(new int(1));
```

or use the [std::make_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) macro:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> a = std::make_shared<int>(1);
```

and create a second shared pointer by passing `a` as an argument to the constructor:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> b(a);
```

Comment: I was actually trying to make it crash :)